# Finding solution(s) to the equation $0=x^a+bx^{a-1}+c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How to find a solution to equation $0=x^a+bx^{a-1}+c$, where $a,b\in\mathcal{R}_+$, $c\in \mathcal{R}_-$. I understand that the solution may not exist, but lets assume that numerically we verified the existence of at least one solution, how would one go about finding the solution in terms of $a,b,c$, or proving that there is no closed form solution.

Comment: Likely can't be done in full generality...

Comment: Assuming domain is positive reals, this is similar to polynomial function. term $x^a$ will dominate so you can only have solutions when $c<0$ or $b<0$ or both. If $c<0$, $b>0$, only one solution is possible as the function will be strictly increasing. If both $b$ and $c$ are negative, you may have two solutions.

Comment: @Vasya, I have reworded the question. If $c<0$ and $ b>0$. Now, I am more concerned if it is at all possible to find these solutions, whether it be one or more.

Comment: @Nitin I have changed the question slightly, however I think you may still be correct, do you have any intuition, other than gut, as to why you might be correct?

Comment: Aside: it's common to make a change of variable $x \mapsto 1/x$ and reduce the problem to one of the form $x^a + bx + c$ (with different $b,c$).

Comment: @Hurkyl: Of course this change of variables is suitable, but do you think that this actually "reduces" the problem? I'm still unsure how we could solve either form.

Comment: @C.Hegg: I expect you're more likely to find existing literature by searching for the  $x^a + x + c$ form. For example, the [general solution to the quintic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) is by takes the solution to $x^5 + x + a$ as an elementary function, and reducing the general quintic to this form.